# Synchronous vuejs2 websql

Tags: vuejs2, web-sql

Really appreciate your support,
My Code Start by Triggering Insert Data function
Which run a websql Insert query ,
then after the data is inserted, i need a to retrieve data using Getdata function to get this data and assign it to array_data

```
<script>
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
import navigationBar from "../components/navigationBar.vue";
export default defineComponent({
  name: "Prod",
  components: {
    navigationBar,
  },
data() {
    return {
      array_data : [],
            }
        },
methods: {
    InsertData() {
       const db = window.openDatabase("data", "1.0", "data", 1 * 1024 * 1024);
       db.transaction((t) => {
         t.executeSql(
           `SQL INSERT Query`,
           [],
           function (t, result) {
                 this.Getdata() ///cant trigger this function
           }
         );
       });
   },
    Getdata() {
      const db = window.openDatabase("data", "1.0", "data", 1 * 1024 * 1024);
      db.transaction((t) => {
        t.executeSql(`SQL SELECT Query`,[],
          (t, result) =>
            (this.array_data = Object.values(result.rows))
        );
      });
    },
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: The inner `function` should be an arrow function:  `(t, result) => {`

Comment: it give me error (error  't' is defined but never used& error  'result' is defined but never used) and if I removed them error is (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Getdata')at eval

Comment: That's a warning, not an error.  Just remove the arguments if you don't need them:  `() => {`

Comment: can i reference the function  Getdata , without arrow function and without this.?

Comment: You could, but there's no reason `this` would be a problem unless you've left in the keyword `function`.  Anyway, at the top of `InsertData`, do `const f = this.Getdata;` (no parentheses), then pass `f` as the 3rd argument instead of the function.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and your support, I really appreciate it